# Extract a column of a list from a text file in C

Tags: c, parsing, file-management

This may be a simple question with a straightforward answer, but searching through the site I didn't find anything (maybe because I'm new to C programming) except for python codes, which I already wrote and it's quite inefficient.

Suppose I have a list of data in a `timestamps.txt` file, formatted like this:

```
<large integer>, <integer between 1 and 8>
<large integer>, <integer between 1 and 8>
```

and so on (the file is about 4GB)...

What I want to do is to copy only the second column to another file, say `singles.txt`.

What I did so far works, but it's a rather naive approach and takes too much time. Here's my code:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE *input_file;
    FILE *output_file;
    char ch;
    int check = 0;

    input_file = fopen("timestamps.txt","r");
    output_file = fopen("singles.dat","w");
    if (!input_file)
        return -1;

    while((ch = getc(input_file))!=EOF)
        {

            if(check==1)
                {putc(ch,output_file);putc('\n',output_file);}

            if(ch == ',')
                check = 2;
            else
                check -= 1;

        }


    fclose(input_file);
    fclose(output_file);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm sure there is a faster way, but I can't seem to make anything work.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what you got til now ?

Comment: Apart from the code I just posted, I just tried various attempts with combinations of `fscanf` and `fprintf`, but nothing working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `fgets` and `fputs` is faster than multiple calls to `getc` and `putc`, all you need is a buffer (a little buffer in this case) to store the current line:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE *input_file;
    FILE *output_file;
    char buf[128];
    char *ptr;

    input_file = fopen("timestamps.txt","r");
    output_file = fopen("singles.dat","w");
    if (!input_file)
        return -1; /* use EXIT_FAILURE instead of -1 */
    /* you forget to check output_file */
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, input_file)) {
       ptr = strchr(buf, ','); /* find the comma */
       if (ptr != NULL) {
           fputs(ptr + 1, output_file); /* +1 to skip the comma */
       }
    }
    fclose(input_file);
    fclose(output_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I didn't add 1 to `ptr`, though, and it worked fine.

What I wrote was `while((fgets(line, sizeof(line),input_file))!=NULL)`
         `{ptr = strchr(line, ' '); fputs(ptr,output_file);}`

The `' '` is because of the space after the comma

Answer (score 0):

Your idea isn't so bad, but you should make your variable `check` either 0 or 1, depending on whether you want to copy the current input data or not. And you must reset the check with each new line.

Alternatively, you could countthe current field your are in and copy the data when the field is the one you want.

Here's a version that copies the column `want` delimited by `sep` verbatim to the output file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE *in = stdin;
    FILE *out = stdout;

    int want = 1;
    int col = 0;
    int sep = ',';

    for (;;) {
        int c = getc(in);

        if (c == EOF) break;

        if (c == sep) {
            col++;
        } else if (c == '\n') {
            col = 0;
            putc(c, out);
        } else if (col == want) {
            putc(c, out);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(I've used `stdin` and `stdout`, because I was lazy and didn't want to do the flie opening and closing stuff.)

Comment: I did it like that because after the comma there is a space, so i set it to 2 when it meets the comma, then the space makes it go to 1 and finally it meets the number I need.

Comment: Yes, but you will only get the space, because after that, `check` is decremented for each character. You change the state with every character, but it should only change when a separator (comma or newline) is found.

Comment: No, I get the space if I set check to 1 when I get to the comma.
The if is before the decrement, so it's like: if->not satisfied: check is a negative number; if->not satisfied: comma-> check gets to 2; if-> nothing: space->check gets to 1; if->satisfied! number copied: number->check goes to zero, but the number is already copied

Comment: Okay, but that is a very specialised version that relies on having a space and a single-digit number. (I know that you have said that it is an integer from 1 to 8. Anyway, it seems as if you'd gotten the answer you were looking for.)